# Add status check to multiple table query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query which finds applications from an impacted table and also a supporting table.  There is a third table which contains more project information that I need to query. One of them is a status field.  I want to add a join to that Project table and have results returned only if the status shows as In Progress.  This is what I have so far:

Example of data and columns

Application Information below

```
Appid ProjectId
 197   251
```

Project Information Columns Below

`ProjectID ProjectName ImplementationDate Status`

```
   select AppId                   = a.AppId,
   ApplicationName         = a.ApplicationName 

 from      Applications           a
 left join ( select AppId = t.AppId ,
               Cnt   = count(*)
        from ImpactedApplications t
        group by t.AppId
      ) ia on ia.AppId = a.AppId
 left join ( select AppId = t.AppId ,
               Cnt   = count(*)
        from SupportingApplications t
        group by t.AppId
      ) sa on sa.AppId = a.AppId
      where sa.Cnt > 0 OR ia.Cnt > 0 ORDER BY ApplicationName ASC
```

Comment: can you give sample data from the Applications, ImpactedApplications, SupportingApplications table

Comment: @Rajesh Added information with examples to my original post.  Hope this helps!

Comment: updated my answer as per the columns, can you check if this works for you

Comment: @Rajesh  The error I get when I use this is:  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'ProjectId'.
Msg 8158, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'CTE' has more columns than were specified in the column list.

Comment: updated the CTE output, can you try now

Comment: @Rajesh Sorry to be a pain.  Returns with Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'ProjectId'.  THe Project ID is not in a.ProjectId.  Applicationtable only has AppIds  It is stored in the ImpactedApplications and SupportingApplications tables as well as the Projects table.

Comment: i changed it to capital ID, is your database settings have case sensitive option

Comment: @Rajesh THe Project ID is not in a.ProjectId.  Applicationtable only has AppIds  It is stored in the ImpactedApplications and SupportingApplications tables as well as the Projects table.  When I changed it to be P.ProjectID as in the bottom area I receive invalid column name.  When I change it to the full name Projects.ProjectID I receive multipart identifier cannot be bound.

Comment: okay your example has projectid as the column in applications Appid ProjectId 197 251, what is the key to join applications and project , is it appid. is project id present in impactedapplications and supportingapplciations?

Comment: @Rajesh Yes projectId is present is impactedapplications and supportingapplications

Comment: rewrote the query with union, if you want you can add distinct , so that duplicates won't come

Comment: @Rajesh I think I may not be explaining it correctly.  Essentially what I want is to just add a Join that also checks the column Projects.Status for 'In Progress'  When I use your most recent query it returns multipart binding errors.  Is there more information I need to give you?

Comment: If you can create a sql fiddle, it would help

Comment: @Rajesh I have a great idea.  Can you post your original answer as well?  I think I have a way to use a combination of the two.

Comment: added original one also

Answer (score 0):

CTE approach

; WITH CTE (appid, ApplicationName, ProjectId)
    AS
    (

```
    select AppId                   = a.AppId,
       ApplicationName         = a.ApplicationName, 
       ProjectId               = a.ProjectId
     from      Applications           a
     left join ( select AppId = t.AppId 
                   Cnt   = count(*)
            from ImpactedApplications t
            group by t.AppId
          ) ia on ia.AppId = a.AppId
     left join ( select AppId = t.AppId 
                   Cnt   = count(*)
            from SupportingApplications t
            group by t.AppId
          ) sa on sa.AppId = a.AppId
          where sa.Cnt > 0 OR ia.Cnt > 0 ORDER BY ApplicationName ASC

)
select * from CTE C
INNER JOIN Porject P
on C.ProjectId = P.ProjectID
and P.Status = 'InProgress'
```

UNION might work here

```
SELECT ApplicationName , P.*
FROM Applications A
INNER JOIN ImpactedApplications IA
on A.AppId = IA.AppId
INNER JOIN Project P
on IA.ProjectId = P.ProjectID
AND P.Status ='InProgress'
UNION
SELECT ApplicationName , P.*
FROM Applications A
INNER JOIN SupportingApplications SA
on A.AppId = SA.AppId
INNER JOIN Project P
on IA.ProjectId = P.ProjectID
AND P.Status ='InProgress'
order by ApplicationName ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong with your existing code you need to join project table with applications table based on projectid on both table and only need to fetch records which have status=InProgress.

```
select AppId                   = a.AppId,
   ApplicationName         = a.ApplicationName, 
   p.*
 from      Applications           a
 left join ( select AppId = t.AppId ,
               Cnt   = count(*)
        from ImpactedApplications t
        group by t.AppId
      ) ia on ia.AppId = a.AppId
 left join ( select AppId = t.AppId ,
               Cnt   = count(*)
        from SupportingApplications t
        group by t.AppId
      ) sa on sa.AppId = a.AppId
 join project p on a.projectid=p.projectid
      where (sa.Cnt > 0 OR ia.Cnt > 0 )
            and p.status='InProgress'
ORDER BY ApplicationName ASC
```

Comment: can you demonstrate?  The tables are impactedapplications supportingapplications and Projects

Comment: @OnceorTwice, as per your code you have even an applications table right? and the Applications and project both have projectid which i joined and put the condition status='InProgress'